# SeekToCurrentErrorHandler with false commitRecovered and BackOff

Tags: spring-kafka

In my application, I would need to no ack the event if the consumer got the exception which is marked ad RetryableException. I did extend the SeekToCurrentErrorHandler to support that. But after sure if I set **commitRecovered** as **false**, is that the event will be retried in the next pool? Or If it passed that backoff period, it won't be retried?

```html
@Override
public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records,
                   Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
    boolean isCommitCovered = false;
    if (this.isCommitRecovered()) {
        isCommitCovered = true;
    } else {
        isCommitCovered = this.retryablePredicate(thrownException).test(this.getRetryableExceptions());
    }

    this.setCommitRecovered(isCommitCovered);

    super.handle(thrownException, records, consumer, container);
}
```

Comment: Best to show your subclass so we can see what you have done; with the standard error handler, the record will be retried after the backoff until the retries are exhausted, after which it is sent to the recoverer.

Comment: I just added the extension for what I am doing. Basically it just check the thrown exception and based on that, it determined it would set the commitRecovered to be false or not. So my question is that if we commitRecovered to be false, do the events retry again regardless what we put into the backoff? Because I don't really understand the purpose of this field while we got the backoff that will stop the retries after that. Kindly correct me if my assumption is not correct

Comment: I do see that on the KafkaMessageListenerContainer(doInvokeRecordListener method), we have ackCurrent(record);
is it the correct way that we can set the ackAfterHandle to be false to let the failed event to be re-tried

Comment: `commitRecovered` has nothing to do with retrying, it means that if the retries are exhausted and the recoverer doesn't throw an exception, the offset is committed. In most cases, it should be true; you should not be changing it at runtime, especially if multiple consumers are using the same error handler; it's not thread-safe. If a record is recovered, and the flag is `false` and the container is restarted before the next offset is committed, you will get the recovered record redelivered. Setting it to `false` would be quite unusual. You certainly don't need to set it conditionally.

Comment: Not-retryable exceptions are recovered immediately, without any retries.

Comment: Sorry if this question is far away from the main topic but regarding to my case, if this solution is not the correct way to go, is it possible to based on the exception type (maybe on recoverer) we can let the event to be retried in the next pool until it's proceeded successfully?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225733/discussion-between-duc-bui-and-gary-russell).